# Huge disparity in classification prediction results in CNN model Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, prediction, conv-neural-network

I trained a `CNN` model with Keras with a `df` of `921 rows x 10165 columns` Each row is a sample with `10160` features. I then used the pretrained model for prediction.

I made sure that the training data was well balanced, with around 50% samples with label `0` and the remaining 50% with label `1`. Model accuracy looks decent but problem during prediction.

So the input data looks like this:

```
X = df.iloc[:,0:10160]  
X = X.to_numpy()                      
X = X.reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1],1]) 
X_train_1 = X[:,0:10080,:]
X_train_2 = X[:,10080:10160,:].reshape(921,80)      
Y = df.iloc[:,10163:10165]
Y = Y.to_numpy()
```

and I predicted the number of samples with predicted label '1' (for `label_1`) with code:

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame(model.predict([X_train_1,X_train_2])) 
prediction['label_1'] = ['0' if x < 0.5 else '1' for x in prediction['prob']]

prediction[prediction['label_1'] == '1'].shape[0]/921
```

The second line of code calculates the fraction of samples with `label_1 ==1` out of all samples. The issue is that given the input data has balanced number of `1` and `0`, I was expecting that the fraction is around 50% or so, but the calculated fraction is between range `0.08`~ `0.98`(if not more extreme) with huge disparity. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: How do you got `prediction['prob']` right after `prediction = pd.DataFrame(model.predict([X_train_1,X_train_2]))`? Its result should be a `DataFrame` with the class names in its column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `model.predict_classes()` instead. Otherwise you're getting probabilities.

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame(model.predict_classes([X_train_1,X_train_2])) 
prediction[prediction['label_1'] == '1'].shape[0]/921
```

If you're using the functional API, use `np.argmax()`:

```
np.argmax(model.predict([X_train_1,X_train_2]), axis=1)
```

Then you will need to predictions you need, as 0 and 1 instead of probabilities.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for the answer. The code returned `AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'` I guess it was because I used `Model` rather than `Sequential` class..

Comment: Hi Nicolas, the code works but I think the problem remains. I actually defined `1` if prob>0.5 and `0` otherwise. With your method it returned `Counter({0: 921})` which means there are 921 `0` and 0 `1`, which is my main concern since the number of `0` and `1` are severely imbalanced..hope this explains my problem a bit clearer. Thanks